# How do I load my .abbrev_defs file only if I am editing a .c or .cpp?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp

Below is my novice .abbrev_defs file for emacs. I don't know if this is the convention way or not. If there is a better way, I would like to know.

```
(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table '(
    ("if" "if()\n  {\n\n  }" nil 1)
    ("else" "else\n  {\n\n  }" nil 1)
    ("while" "while()\n  {\n\n  }" nil 1)
    ("for" "for(;;)\n  {\n\n  }" nil 1)
    ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of mode-specific abbrev tables. For the c-mode and c++-modes, you'd add:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'c-mode-abbrev-table '(
    ("if" "if()\n  {\n\n  }" nil 1)
    ("else" "else\n  {\n\n  }" nil 1)
    ("while" "while()\n  {\n\n  }" nil 1)
    ("for" "for(;;)\n  {\n\n  }" nil 1)
    ))

(define-abbrev-table 'c++-mode-abbrev-table '(
    ("if" "if()\n  {\n\n  }" nil 1)
    ("else" "else\n  {\n\n  }" nil 1)
    ("while" "while()\n  {\n\n  }" nil 1)
    ("for" "for(;;)\n  {\n\n  }" nil 1)
    ))
```

At first, I was concerned about the repetition, but in theory, you'd probably want to have abbreviations for c++ specific constructs in `c++-mode-abbrev-table`.

Alternatively, you could go with [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) [http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/] for more features.